# How to add relative layout to relative layout dynamically after a pattern?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-relativelayout

I'm looking for a solution on how to add dynamic relative layout on a parent relative layout after a pattern for dynamic layout.

For example the parrent rl have 2 other rl. Those rl I want to add them dynamically

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/providerServiceRL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/dynamic1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="123dp" >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="zzzz" />

    <TextView
          android:id="@+id/section_label44"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
           android:text="kkkkk" />
      </RelativeLayout>

         <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dynamic1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="96dp" >

           <TextView
              android:id="@+id/section_label2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="zzzz122" />

              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/section_label448"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/section_label2"
                android:text="kkkkk" />
         </RelativeLayout>

      </RelativeLayout>
```

Something like TableRow, but with the row split into two horizontal rows (I've tried that without success).

Or any other idea will be great.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.zzzzRL);

for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
  RelativeLayout rlDynamic=new RelativeLayout(this);
  rl.addView(rlDynamic);
}
```

Comment: Pleas explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem *by editing your answer*.